# Jest testcase breaking in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, expo

Following is the error I receive on running a Sample testcase:

```
Expected react-native/jest-preset to define transform[^.+\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$]
react-native/jest-preset contained different transformIgnorePatterns than expected
 FAIL  ./App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox' from 'setup.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-expo/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:299:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js:155:6)
```

My Testcase:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from './App';

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('has 1 child', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
    expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

My jest configuration in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)",
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button)/)"
    ]
  },
```

My dependencies in `package.json`:

```
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
```

`expo version`: `37.0.0`

`react`: `16.9.0

`react-native`: `"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz"`

Comment: Found a similar issue on expo forums: https://forums.expo.io/t/cannot-find-module-react-native-libraries-logbox-logbox-from-setup-js/43439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution on the Expo thread mentioning the exact same issue [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/cannot-find-module-react-native-libraries-logbox-logbox-from-setup-js/43439/3?u=maniac-tech).

> It looks like you’re using jest-expo v39 with a project running SDK37. LogBox was released with React Native 0.63 which is what SDK39 is using. Can you try running with v37.0.0 and see if that resolves the issue?